# Graph Multiple Series with Column Value Evaluated

Tags: macros

I am pretty new to macro, and have always been working with easier language like SQL.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

I am pretty sure my code looks funny and amusing~

Goal:

1. GRAPH COLUMN(H) AS X, COLUMN(I) AS Y
2. EVALUATE COLUMN(J) AS VALUE TO SET ROW RANGE FOR 4 DIFFERENT RANGES
3. RANGE1 <= 5, 5 < RANGE2 <= 10, 10 < RANGE3 <= 15, RANGE4 > 15
4. RETURN DIFFERENT SERIES ON SCATTER GRAPH FOR THE RESPECTIVE RANGE

**FOLLOWING IS THE MACRO I HAVE TRIED:**

```
Private Sub GRAPH()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FINALROW = Sheet1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
RowRange = Sheet1.Range(J2, "J" & FINALROW).Row

If RowRange <= 5 Then
ROW5 = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows(H2, "H" & FINALROW)).Row
End If

If RowRange <= 10 Then
ROW10 = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows(H2, "H" & FINALROW)).Row
End If

If RowRange <= 15 Then
ROW15 = WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows(H2, "H" & FINALROW)).Row
End If

sheetname = ActiveSheet.Name

Charts.Add
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Columns("H:I")

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range("H" & ROW5, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range("H" & ROW10, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).XValues = Range("H" & ROW15, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).XValues = Range("H" & FINALROW, lastcell2)

ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).YValues = Range("I" & ROW5, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).YValues = Range("I" & ROW10, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(3).YValues = Range("I" & ROW15, lastcell2)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(4).YValues = Range("I" & FINALROW, lastcell2)

End Sub
```